# For some I’m four, and to others, even more

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix is money
>   My infix is workforce
>   My suffix if corrected
>   Refers to some source
>
> Some say I’m three
>   And to some I’m four
>   To some, I’m many
>   To others, even more

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This may be

> dimension

My prefix is money

> dime - 10 cents in the US

My infix is workforce

> men - a dated term for a workforce

My suffix if corrected, Refers to some source

> Sion, one spelling of Zion, or Jerusalem, which may have the etymology "foundation".

Some say I’m three, and to some I’m four, To some, I’m many, To others, even more

> Three of space, four in space-time, and mathematicians study any number of dimensions.

Comment: I really like how this fits with the last stanza

Comment: rot13(Avpryl qbar! Gur fhssvk vf abg jung V vagraqrq –– vg jnf fhccbfrq gb pbagnva gur vasvk nf jryy –– lrg vg frrzf nyy gur zber vagrerfgvat). I'm a fan of brevity and your last line is a treat to read!

Answer (score 8):

I think the word might be

> few

My prefix is money

> f can be an abbreviation for farthing

My infix is workforce

> e can be an abbreviation for erg, a unit of work done by a force

My suffix if corrected
Refers to some source

> w "corrected" could be m, which can be an abbreviation for mother, certainly a source.

Some say I’m three
And to some I’m four
To some, I’m many
To others, even more

> few can be used to refer to 3 or more objects